# getting closed form of recursion equation and compare which is faster

Tags: recursion, time, complexity-theory

Get closed form of these equations if possible. Then, determine which would be faster than the other.

```
f(n) = 0.25f(n/3)+ f(n/10) + logn, f(1) =  1

g(n) = n + log(n-1)^2 + 1
```

In these equations, do I have to expand these recursions and try to discover patterns within? I really don't know how to calculate closed form intuitively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: `g(n)>f(n)`
Long answer: g is not even recursive, so you can see immediately that g(n)=O(n).
You can approximate `f(n) <f(n/2)+logn`
which, by the master theorem, is Θ(logn)

Comment: I'm trying to add the greek letter Theta, but cant seem to do it. can you add Latex code to stack overflow?

Comment: changed it (and rolled it back) without any effect :(